# How to keep the order of slices fixed in a pie chart? [d3]

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have this array of objects

```
const data = [
 {id: 0, type: "inc", amount: 3000},
 {id: 1, type: "exp", amount: 1500}
]
```

When I pass this data to a d3 pie function

```
const pie = d3.pie().value(d => d.amount);
```

the `inc` entry will have `index: 0` while `exp` entry will have `index: 1`. My understanding, d3 by default assign the largest value `index` 0, which means `startAngle` will be 0 for the largest value, and goes on in descending order of the values.

In my case, the application can change the amount of either entry. The default behavior of d3 swaps the order of `inc` and `exp` in the pie chart once `exp` amount exceeds that of `inc`. I want the entry of type `inc` to always start from `startAngle` 0, even if `exp` entry's amount exceeds that of `inc` entry. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

To those who are interested in the answer, it turned out you can define a `compare` function inside the `sort` method of the `pie` function like so

```
const pie = d3.pie().value(d => d.amount).sort((a) => {
      if (a.type === 'inc') {
        return -1;
      } else {
        return 1;
      }
    });
```

This will keep the `inc` entry with `index: 0` all the time, regardless of the `amount` value compared to the `exp` entry